# how to solve codesign fail on mac with jenkis ci and electron-builder?

Tags: jenkins, electron, electron-builder

when i build in terminal codesign suceess but when i build in jenkins ci, throw error always.

the error content:

file=build/mac/VIPThink-test-online.app identityName=Developer ID xxxx identityHash=xxx provisioningProfile=none
Error: Command failed: codesign --sign xxx --force /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/pc-student-build-test/build/mac/VIPThink-test-online.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/pc-student-build-test/build/mac/VIPThink-test-online.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework: errSecInternalComponent

Answer (score 3):

1st> just type this code in terminal 
export CSC_IDENTITY_AUTO_DISCOVERY=false

2nd> run electron-builder --mac zip 
It will temporarily create a zip without sign in key

It also successfully build the project for mac